# python3 subprocess returning local encoding bytes makes information lost

Tags: windows, python-3.x, subprocess

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess as sp
import locale

LOCAL_ENCODING = locale.getpreferredencoding()

cmds = ['dir', '/b', '*.txt']

out = sp.check_output(cmds, shell=True)
print(out)
print(out.decode(LOCAL_ENCODING))

s = 'レミリア・スカレート.txt'
print(s.encode(LOCAL_ENCODING, 'replace'))
print(LOCAL_ENCODING)
# print(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

This is the output:

```
b'\xa5\xec\xa5\xdf\xa5\xea\xa5\xa2?\xa5\xb9\xa5\xab\xa5\xec\xa9`\xa5\xc8.txt\r\n'
レミリア?スカレート.txt

b'\xa5\xec\xa5\xdf\xa5\xea\xa5\xa2?\xa5\xb9\xa5\xab\xa5\xec\xa9`\xa5\xc8.txt'
cp936
```

(A text file named `'レミリア・スカレート.txt'` is in the script directory.)

As the result shows, the bytes of the file name returned  **has been automatically encoded by local encoding**, which can't totally encode the filename(Note the `?` in the bytes), thus some information lost.

> Environment:
>   - win10 Chinese Simplified
>   - python-3.5.1

**My question is:**
Is it possible to avoid the automatical local-encoding and get an utf-8(or some other specified encoding) bytes?
I read this [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue6135), but got no solution :-(

---

**1.For built-in command, solved by eryksun's answer:**

> `out = sp.check_output('cmd.exe /u /c "dir /b *.txt"').decode('utf-16le')`,
>   `/u`: Output UNICODE characters (UCS-2 le),
>   `/c`: Run Command and then terminate)

**2.For external programs:[no general solution]**
configure the output using proper encoding(by setting exteral programs' options or configurations, of course, *such options may be nonexistent*),
for example, in the latest winrar, one can set the encoding of console rar messages:`rar lb -scur data > list.txt`, will produce Unicode list.txt with archived file names

Comment: UTF-16 is the only Unicode output that the cmd shell supports, and that's *only* for the output of built-in commands such as `dir`. External programs run via the cmd shell can write whatever they want to the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` handles.

Comment: If you're just getting the output of a built-in command, then manually run the shell using `cmd.exe /u /c` instead of using `shell=True`, e.g. `out = sp.check_output('cmd.exe /u /c "dir /b *.txt"').decode('utf-16le')`. Note that you should use a command line string with the shell since it follows different rules than `subprocess.list2cmdline`.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for pointing that out. That does work! And I made an another try(external program): compress the txt in a winrar archive, say `test.rar` and list filenames in `test.rar`, then `out = sp.check_output(['rar', 'vb',  'test.rar']); print(out)`, I also got `b'\xa5\xec\xa5\xdf\xa5\xea\xa5\xa2?\xa5\xb9\xa5\xab\xa5\xec\xa9`\xa5\xc8.txt\r\n'`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Use a rar program that writes its output using UTF-8 or UTF-16 or has a command line option or environment variable to configure the output encoding. Otherwise, changing the system locale in Windows may help in a specific case, but it can't help in general because it has to be a non-Unicode code page, i.e. it cannot be CP1200 (UTF-16LE) or CP65001 (UTF-8).

Comment: After an hour searching, I find the rar tricks, but only exists in the latest version [rarnew](http://www.rarlab.com/rarnew.htm) : New 'R' object for -sc switch defines encoding of console RAR messages sent to redirected files and pipes. For example:`rar lb -scur data > list.txt` will produce Unicode list.txt with archived file names. Thanks for the general guide @eryksun :)

Comment: Is that UTF-8 or UTF-16, and does it have an initial byte order mark (BOM) when the output is read from a pipe?

Comment: BTW, if you're running python.exe as the child process, then you can set `PYTHONIOENCODING` in its environment to override the default encoding, e.g. `environ = os.environ.copy();` `environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf-8';` `out = sp.check_output(['python', ...], env=environ).decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: You can write up an answer for this if you want. It's not a very satisfying answer since there's no general solution but instead a collection of ad hoc solutions specific to each program.

Comment: It's utf-16-le without BOM, now  the output filename bytes is `b'\xec0\xdf0\xea0\xa20\xfb0\xb90\xab0\xec0\xfc0\xc80.\x00t\x00x\x00t\x00\r\x00\n\x00'` @eryksun